# How to get rid of undefined offset?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove undefined offset error from the following code but could not figure it how.

```
$number = 20;
$pack = 10;
$i = 0;
while ($number % $pack == 0)
{
    $number = $number / $pack;
    $i++;
}
list($firstpart,$secondpart)=explode('.', $number);

echo $firstpart;
echo '<br>';
echo isset($secondpart)? number_format($secondpart,0):'0';
```

This code gives me correct answer but it outputs the following error:

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 1 -- at line 11

How do I change my code to remove the error. In a case like when $number=20.5, there is no error. Thanks.

Comment: `explode('.', $number)` is set to `$firstpart`, but what's about second part ?

Comment: Some time $number can have decimal point. That's why I need the second part also.

Comment: @Zl3n What if the result of the division produces more than one decimal point? You will lose that precision with your proposed solution.

Comment: `list($firstpart, $secondpart) = explode('.', $number.(strpos($number, '.') === false ? ".0" : ''));`

Comment: Please can you post your answer with explanation because it works and I want to accept.

Comment: Sure thing. One moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
list($firstpart, $secondpart) = explode('.', $number.(strpos($number, '.') === false ? ".0" : ''));
```

And here is an explanation so I don't get accused of witchcraft :-)

```
list($firstpart, $secondpart) =
    explode(
        '.', // explode on a period
        $number.(strpos($number, '.') === false ? ".0" : '') // if the number does not contain a period then manually add ".0" so that explode can work but if it does then just leave it as-is
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use two arguments for `list()` it attempts to reference index `[0]` and `[1]` from the `explode()`, however there is only `[0]` because `explode()` returns only one array element when there is no `.`.  Use this instead:

```
$parts = explode('.', $number);
echo $parts[0];
echo isset($parts[1]) ? number_format($parts[1] ,0) : '0';
```